# mensajes en red

Tags: windows, msg

tengo una duda si alguien puede orientarme .... en la of tenemos varias oficinas en las cuales hemos tenido algunos problemas con usuarios.... recuerdo el antiguo comando net send para enviar mensajes en red... por lo que estaba pensando en hacer (muy ordinario) botón de pánico ... el cual consta de un bat que al ejecutar mande un msg de alerta a las demás pcs conectadas en red .... mi problema ... no encuentro la manera de ejecutar bien el comando msg, me salen errores de "no reconoce nombre, error 5, etc ... copio como ejecuto el mensaje

```
msg /server:192.168.1.21  "hola"
```

otro q probe un boton en vb

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/K msg /server:192.168.1.21 */time:20 hola Enviado esde el PC: %computername%");
```

no se si existe otra manera

Answer (score 0):

Viendo la sintaxis del comando ( https://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/msg-command/ ) da la sensación de que te falta añadir el usuario o bien * para todos los usuarios...

```
msg * /server:servername /time:seconds /v /w /? messagetext
```